How to divide a bibliography and use \nocite{*}?
I'm writing a document with xelatex. I want to cite all the references of my bibile, even those I do not cite in the text.
I have a master document file :
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
\input{preambule}
\title{The Title}
\author{Happy Bobby}


\begin{document}
%\maketitle
%\mainmatter

\chapter{The First Chapter}
\input{First}
etc.

\section*{Bibliography}
\printbibliography[keyword=Primary,title=Primary Sources]
\printbibliography[keyword=Secondary,title=Secondary Sources]
\end{document}

In my preambule, I have :
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=4cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

[...]
\usepackage[maxlevel=3]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=verbose-trad2,bibstyle=verbose-trad2,citepages=omit]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliographie.bib}
\nocite{*}

I have a long bibliography I want to divide into two parts, which I can do but I can't manage to have all my references. The final bibliography only shows the references cited in the text.

I'm sorry but this doesn't really show what you're doing, and has a lot of likely irrelevant stuff. You need to construct a document that replicates your problem with a small includable .bib file like the example I gave. What happens if you use your .bib file with my example? Does it work? Also you need to be more explicit in saying what doesn't work.

It's ok. As I said, I have the same problem with your example when I use my bibfile. I get the two references cited, but not my complete bibfile. I don't know what I can add in my answer to make it more useful... I wonder if it wouldn't be easier to split my bibfile into two bibfiles.

Do all of the entries in your .bib file have a keywords field? They won't show up in your split bibliography without that.

@Allan Munn Yes, of course !

You can just use a single \nocite{*} command in your document and the keyword sorting will split the references as you desire:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}

@book{knuth:ct:a,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    title = {The {\TeX book}},
    volume = {A},
    keywords={Primary}}
    
@book{companion,
    author = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
    edition = 1,
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    title = {The {LaTeX} Companion},
    keywords= {Secondary}}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=verbose-trad2,bibstyle=verbose-trad2,citepages=omit]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}
\begin{document}

\section*{Bibliography}
\printbibliography[keyword=Primary,title=Primary Sources]
\printbibliography[keyword=Secondary,title=Secondary Sources]
\end{document}



I tried :\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=verbose-trad2,bibstyle=verbose-trad2,citepages=omit]{biblatex} \bibliography{Bibliographie} \nocite{*}  in my preamble but I don't have my complete bibliography. Have I to use the \filecontent command ?

@happybobby Use \addbibresource{your-bib-file.bib} instead of using \bibliography. Note the .bib extension. No, the \filecontents environment is just for the example.

I already tried, but I get the same result : only the cited references

@happybobby Then you need to edit your question to give an actual example (not just code fragments) that shows what you're doing. My example works for you, yes?

Yes, I get the same thing than you, but not my complete bibfile. I'm editing the question.

I tried to use only \nocite{*}, without trying to sort my references and I still only get my cited references. So I believe the problem does not come from sorting the bibliography, but from printing the whole bibfile...

Actually, the problem came from the cross-references because some labels had changed. I had to rerun biber and xelatex, despite a three-times compilation at first,to print the whole bibfile.
I can use either \bibliography{bibfile} or \addbibresource{bibfile.bib} and \nocite{*} in the preamble and sort the bibliography as I intended with \print{bibliography}[keyword=Primary] etc.

So my solution is in fact correct. Perhaps you should accept it, then.

Of course ! I'm not a big user of the stack exchange, so I don't have all the reflexes.
